# Saving an entry with multiple parentheses throw a 403

Tags: craft3, redactor

Saving an entry with multiple parentheses (in a redactor field) throw a 403. I know it's from ModSecurity - but never experienced that behaviors with another CMS (WP, Kirby, etc.) or with Craft2. This issue appears on 2 (different) projects in development.

Is anyone got something similar?

---

**Field details:**

- Clean up HTML : checked
- Purify HTML : checked
- HTML Purifier Config : Default
- Column Type : 64KB

---

PS. If I remove the `()` from the text or replace them with brackets `[]`, the entry saved correctly. We experienced that issue on multiple computers from different offices and didn't reproduce it on local environment (MAMP or XAMP) - so it's not machine/location oriented.

PPS. Deactivate ModSecurity is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you check the ModSecurity logs, you can find exactly which of its rules Redactor/that POST request is tripping.

You can either modify that rule to allow it to pass or just disabled that specific rule.